# How to access namespaced vuex inside router

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

i tried to access vuex getters with namespaced modules inside routers.js but the getters always returning null value while the value is true(user logged in)

here is the example code.

**store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import auth from './auth'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth
  }
});
```

**store/auth/index.js**

```js
import axios from "axios"

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    status: null
  },

  getters: {
    authenticated(state) {
      return state.token && state.user && state.status;
    },

    user(state) {
      return state.user;
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
      state.token = token;
    },
    SET_USER(state, data) {
      state.user = data;
    },
    SET_STATUS(state, status) {
      state.status = status
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async logIn({ dispatch }, data) {
      let response = await axios.post('back/in', data);

      return dispatch('attemptLogin', response.data.token)
    },

    async attemptLogin({ commit, state }, token) {
      if (token) {
        commit('SET_TOKEN', token);
        commit('SET_STATUS', true);
      }

      if (!state) {
        return
      }

      try {
        let response = await axios.get('back/me')

        commit('SET_USER', response.data.user)
      } catch (e) {
        commit('SET_USER', null)
        commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
        commit('SET_STATUS', null);
      }
    }
  },

}
```

**store/subscriber.js**

```js
import store from '../store'
import axios from 'axios'


store.subscribe((mutation) => {
  switch (mutation.type) {
    case 'auth/SET_TOKEN':
      if (mutation.payload) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer  ${mutation.payload}`;
        localStorage.setItem('token', mutation.payload)
      } else {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
        localStorage.setItem('token')
      }

      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
})
```

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Login from '../views/Login';
import LoggedInLayout from '../layouts/LoggedInLayout';
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard';
import Post from '../views/pages/Post/Index';
import store from '../store'


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      title: 'Login Page',
      path: '/backend/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        mustLoggedIn: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/backend',
      component: LoggedInLayout,
      children: [
        {
          title: 'Dashboard',
          path: '/backend/dashboard',
          name: 'dashboard',
          component: Dashboard
        },
        {
          path: '/backend/post',
          name: 'post',
          component: Post
        },
      ],
      meta: {
        mustLoggedIn: true
      }
    },

  ]
});


router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.mustLoggedIn)) {
    console.log(store.getters['auth/authenticated']); // and everytime i tried to console log, it always return null 
    if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']) {
      next({
        path: '/backend/login'
      })
    } else {
      next('/backend/dashboard')
    }
  } else {
    next() 
  }
})

export default router;
```

**app.js**

```js
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from './store';
import router from './router'
import MainApp from './layouts/MainApp.vue'
import axios from 'axios';
require('./store/subscriber')

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

store.dispatch('auth/attemptLogin', localStorage.getItem('token'));

new Vue({
    router: router,
    store,
    render: h => h(MainApp)
}).$mount('#app');
```

and yeah, when i tried to validate if the user is loggedin throught console log always returning null value, and i stuck with this problem for 1 hour already, can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is your auth module's `state`?

Comment: Do you have the login information stored as persistent values, I mean, in the local storage and once you reload the page, the login info still there?

Comment: @Phil, sorry, i ady edited it just no and there's the state

Comment: @AndresForonda, yes even in devtools

Comment: With all your state properties initialised to `null`, if any of them are `null` when you try to access the getter, the result will be `null`. Two questions... 1) Where are your mutations for the auth module, and 2) Where are you committing them?

Comment: Where are you setting the values as persistent? Share your whole code please, because your state is not getting the values once the store runs the first time. To have an example, set as default some values that pass the validation, I mean, test the getter by set token, user and status in true, then put the getter before the meta validation.

Comment: ok, i updated the whole code just now

Answer (score -1):

You are just syncing your store with local-storage. You also need to persist it for it to stay on after reload etc.,

You will need to use something like `vuex-persist`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you get error on "back/me" ?

Try to add "consol.error" in the catch block!

However, why login page has meta "mustLoggedIn" setted true ?